# Sending BYTE* over socket

Tags: c++, pointers, winsock

I'm trying to send a BYTE* over a socket, but the send function only allows me to send a char* buffer. Is this possible? How would I go about casting it back on the other side?

Comment: Have you tried casting?: `send(socket, reinterpret_cast<char*>(byte), sizeof(byte), flag)`.

Comment: @0x499602D2: in your example, assuming `byte` is a `BYTE*`, thus `sizeof(byte)` is always 4 on 32bit systems, and 8 on 64bit systems. `sizeof()` would only work if `byte` is a fixed array instead.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Typo. Should be `sizeof(BYTE)`, right?

Comment: @0x499602D2: No, that's even worse, because `sizeof(BYTE)` is always 1.  So unless you are actually sending 1 byte at a time, you need to specify the real number of bytes that are being pointed at in the second parameter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `reinterpret_cast` to cast from `BYTE*` to `char*`. A `BYTE` [is an `unsigned char` typedef](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383751%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), so you shouldn't have any issues.

```
char* foo = reinterpret_cast<char*>(bar);
```

Where `bar` is your `BYTE*`.

Comment: Thanks yeah that's what I've been doing I've actually figured out that the problem may not be due to the cast. When I cast it the char* only seems to have 9 characters rather than the 1000 there should be! Any ideas on this?

Comment: @Nathelol: That implies that you are passing the wrong value in the third parameter, such as if you are using `strlen()` on binary data, for instance.

Comment: It would look that way if the 10th byte is a zero. But that is just a debugger viewing characteristic.

Comment: the BYTE* is a pointer to byte[0] in byte[3][1000] so when it's cast with reinterpret_cast<BYTE*>(buffers[0]); it only takes the first 9 as in byte[0][0], byte[0][1]... etc