# Sending NULL data over a socket

Tags: linux, sockets, c++11

I am currently attempting to communicate with an external application over TCP/IP based socket. I have successfully established a connection with the client and received some data. This manual [here](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1179.txt) states that

> After this command is received, the client must read an acknowledgement 
>   octet from the daemon.  A positive acknowledgement is an octet of  zero bits.  A negative acknowledgement is an octet of any other pattern.

I would like to send a positive acknowledgment and I am sending it this way
My server listening code was obtained from [here](http://www.bogotobogo.com/cplusplus/sockets_server_client.php)

```
void WriteData(std::string content)
{
    send(newsockfd,content.c_str(),content.length(),0);
}

WriteData("00000000");
```

My question is if I am sending this data corectly (octet of zero bits) ?

Update:

I have read this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27513776/sending-byte-over-socket) 
which states that send only allows to send a char* array. So I am not sure how I can send a byte over a socket. I know i could do something like this

```
std::bitset<8> b1 ;  // [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
```

but i am not sure how i would send that over a socket.

Comment: dont know why the negative vote or the close

Comment: `"00000000" ` is an 8-character string, not an offer.

Comment: `"00000000"` is an eight-character string followed by a null byte. Not an octet of zero bits.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning that could you suggest a method that shows how i can send an octet over a socket since a socket only takes a char array

Comment: An octet is eight bits. One char. An octet of zero bits is a char valued zero.

Comment: "An octet is a unit of digital information in computing and telecommunications that consists of eight bits. " https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octet_(computing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
WriteData(std::string("\0",1));
```

using your function or even:

```
const char null_data(0);
send(newsockfd,&null_data,1,0);
```

to send it directly.

---

```
WriteData("00000000");
```

Will actually sends 8 octets of 48 [decimal] (assuming your platform is ASCII which all modern systems are compatible with).

However `\0` is the escape sequence used in string literals to represent the null character (that is the zero octet).

There's a conflation (mixing together) in C++ between the notions of characters and bytes that dates back to the earliest days of C and is pretty much baked in.

Comment: seems like the second method did the trick while `WriteData("\0")` does not work

Comment: @MistyD, Silly me. Of course it didn't. That constructor for `std::string` would see that null as the terminator. Fixed now.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Sort of a bit. C++ implementations don't as standard offer very good handling for multi-byte characters. But in the range we're dealing with ASCII and all standard encodings of Unicode overlap. I've amended the answer to say 'ASCII *compatible*'. I would agree nearly all modern systems are Unicode and UTF-8 is generally used as the lowest common denominator encoding.