# Sending null byte over a socket to a Windows Machine from Linux - Will it be same

Tags: c++, linux, windows, sockets

This is based on an earlier [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34563947/sending-null-data-over-a-socket) I asked . Currently I am sending an octet of zero bits to linux from a linux machine as such over a socket

```
const char null_data(0);
send(newsockfd,&null_data,1,0);
```

My question is will this be the same when sending to a windows machine (64 bits) ?
or will I have to change the code ?

Comment: Why would it be different? 0 is 0 regardless of platform.

Comment: `sizeof(char)` is not guaranteed to always equal 1. `char` can be multibyte.

Comment: It is. If it's 4 octets then multiply the return of sizeof by 4 to have the size in octets.

Comment: @ScottM C++ Standard guarantees the size of `char` to be 1 byte even if a single byte is larger than 8 bites.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious: Compiler flags exist to assume multibyte characters, hence the need for `stdint.h` and `cstdint`. I'd have to search a bit, but I seem to recall a MSVC flag that aliases `char` to `wchar_t` (I'm working off memory here.)

Comment: @ScottM: No, it has a type `TCHAR` that can be either 8 or 16 bits. Type `char` is always 8 bits under MSVC, and is always by definition 1 byte (`CHAR_BIT` bits) under any conforming C or C++ implementation.

Comment: @KeithThompson: True for the WinXX platform that TCHAR is supposed to be used in place of `char` when MBCS support is turned on. Still safer for the OP to explicitly use `uint8_t` instead of `char`: it tells the reader exactly what's being sent and how large the quantity is. Reduces ambiguity.

Comment: @ScottM: You are confusing character encoding with type sizes. `sizeof(char)` is equal to 1, regardless of compiler settings. A codepoint in Unicode can be encoded using multiple code units.

Comment: @IInspectable: See the standard spec quote in the other answer. The standard doesn't guarantee that `sizeof(char) * 8 == 1 * 8`, just that it has to be sufficiently large. Now, as pointed out, it is generally universal that `sizeof(char) * 8 == 1 * 8`, but there's a lot of value added to being explicit with using `uint8_t`, where the octet guarantee holds.

Comment: @ScottM: If `CHAR_BIT > 8`, then `uint8_t` will not exist. You can use that as a kind of compile-time assertion that `CHAR_BIT==8` -- though an explicit `#if` and `#error` might be clearer. Note also that `uint8_t` is unsigned, while `char` may be either signed or unsigned.

Comment: @ScottM: `sizeof(char)` is **defined** to be equal to 1. Each and every conforming C++ implementation has to go by that. This implies, that `sizeof(char) * 8 == 1 * 8`. Always. You are talking about something different, but it is not clear, what you are talking about.

Comment: @KeithThompson: Looking through header files, quite a few compilers define `uint8_t` as a compiler internal data type and not necessarily as `unsigned char` (which is probably what the original OP code should have used instead of `char`.) It can be compiler implementation dependent.

Comment: See [this code monk](https://drj11.wordpress.com/2007/04/08/sizeofchar-is-1/) post for an example discussion of when `sizeof(char) == 1`, but the byte size is 16 on the the TI C54x DSP.

Comment: @ScottM Those compiler flags have dick to do with the Standard, I suggest you read it. You can argue about it all you want but until the Standard is changes your perception about the size of `char` is wrong.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious: Agreed that compiler flags have little to do with the standard, but then again, the standard doesn't define a byte as 8 bits either. `CHAR_BITS` doesn't have to equal 8 and I've worked on platforms where it isn't (retro PDP-8 platforms and custom embedded devices by obscure contractors.)

Comment: It doesn't matter if a byte is 1 bit or 1000 bites it's still _one_ byte and `sizeof` returns the size of a type in....what for it......waiiiiit for.....bytes!. Feel free to continue grasping at straws until you find a hair to split.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious: There's a difference between a standard-conforming and a nonstandard compiler. Seriously.

Comment: @ScottM: MSVC is (and always has been) standard-conforming in this respect. Seriously, give it a rest. You were wrong. No big deal, we all make mistakes. But really, trying that desperately to make the wrong sound right is very annoying.

Comment: @IInspectable: My point has been and remains that `sizeof(char)` is not an octet on all platforms and that I've run into non-portable environment where `sizeof(char) != 1` despite what the standard says. Plan and simple. Hence the caution on assuming that everything is standards compliant. Read code monk's post for a reasonable summary.

Comment: @ScottM: It's certainly true that `char` is not necessarily an octet (more precisely, that `CHAR_BIT` is not necessarily equal to 8). It's commonly 16 or 32 on DSPs. As for your claim that there are non-conforming environments where `sizeof (char) != 1`, I am skeptical. We can agree that such an environment would be non-conforming, but I've never heard of such a non-conforming environment that actually exists. Can you cite a specific example? (Do you now agree that MSVC does not qualify?) The code monk post does *not* support this claim.

Comment: @ScottM: Please do read code monk's post again, to understand what it is really saying. There is no mention of any platform, where `sizeof(char)` would be different from 1. The blog post contains numerous samples, where people take that to mean: *"a char is a byte is an octet"*. That's where things go wrong, and I presume, that's your understanding as well. I never claimed, that a `char` (or a byte in C++) would be exactly 8 bits, and yet you keep repeating, what I already know (and never publicly challenged).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick here is to use the `uint*_t` data types, insofar as feasible:

```
#include <cstdint>

/* ... */

#if !defined(__WIN64)
// *nix variant
typedef int socket_fd_t;
#else
// WinXX socket descriptor data type.
typedef SOCKET socket_fd_t;
#endif

void send_0_byte(socket_fd_t newsockfd)
{
    uint8_t zero_byte(0);
    send(newsockfd, &zero_byte, 1, 0);
}
```

You probably want to add some error checking code, include the correct platform socket header. `uint8_t` is an 8-bit quantity (octet) by definition, which meets your requirement and avoids potential `char` size issues.

On the receiver side, you want to `recv` into a `uint8_t` buffer.